# Which Join do i use for update when one of my table is empty for a common id?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I am using a left to update values in multiple table .  I have three table a b and c . i have a common id for all three tables. But i need to update all the tables in one go even if one of the tables does not have a entry ? is it possible. which join do i use ?

Comment: _i have a common id for all three tables_ do you mean `foreign key`

Comment: Provide the DDL and the update that needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple LEFT JOINs with a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
GROUP BY a.id
```